# Unable to identify text segments based on keywords

Tags: python

I have potentially large amount of text output coming from an application. The output can be broken up into different sections. And I would like to determine which section I am processing based on existence of 1 or more keywords or key phrases.

Dummy Example output:

```
******************
**   MyApp 1.1  **
**              **
******************
**Copyright     **
******************
Note # 1234
Text of the note 1234
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
******************
INPUT INFO:
Number of data points: 123456
Number of cases:  983
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
******************
Analysis Type: Simple
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
******************
Results:
Data 1: 1234e-10
Data 2
------
1 2
2 3.4
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
*******************
CPU TIME: 1:01:12
WALL TIME: 1:04:23
*******************
```

So I created a dictionary like and am trying to look up the values of the dict in each chunk.

```
def process(this_chunk):
    keys = ['banner_k','runSummary','inputSummary_k']
    vals = [['MyApp','Copyright'],['CPU TIME'],['Number of data']]

    for k,v in zip(keys,vals):
        chunkdict[k]=v

    for k,v in chunkdict.items():
        if any(x in v for x in this_chunk.splitlines()):
            print(k + " is in this chunk")
            process_for_k(chunk) #Function for each specific section.
            break
        else:
            print(k + " is not in this chunk")
    return
```

But this does not identify all the chunks. The values are indeed present but only in 1 chunk the values are matched. To be specific, my real application has the exact words for 'CPU TIME' and 'Copyright' in its output. 
The section with 'CPU TIME' is captured correctly but the section with 'Copyright' is not found.

Is this the right approach to identifying sections with known keywords? 
Any ideas why this (*if any(x in v for x in this_chunk.splitlines()):*)cmight not work?

Comment: `v` is a list of strings, so I wonder how you get matches at all...

Comment: Ideally for me v could be a list of strings and not just 1 string. But I have now tried with just 1 string for value of each key and that didn't work at all. What I have now, a list of strings in some cases, works. Strange.